# Evaluation of $\sum\limits_{i = 0}^s {\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}} q \\ {{2^i}} \end{array}} \right)}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Assume that $q=2^s$ for some non-negative integer $s$. Is there any simple formula for:

$$\sum\limits_{i = 0}^s {\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  q \\ 
  {{2^i}} 
\end{array}} \right)}?$$

Answer (score 3):

I doubt it. I have computed the values for $1\le s\le 10$. Here are the first five:
$$
3, 11, 107, 14827, 611635179
$$
There is no sequence matching them in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org).